# Need to select every 2nd column excel

Tags: excel, multiple-columns

I have a lot of data in one row, separated by columns.

Ex: A, B, C, D, E, F, G (...)

I need every 2nd column to be merged in one column, for a total of 2 columns.

Ex:

Column 1 
A
C
E
G

Column 2
B
D
F
H
And so on..

How can I select every 2nd column in Excel?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `A` is in A1 please try in A2 copied across and down:

```
=OFFSET(A$1,,2*(ROW()-1))
```